# swap stylesheet for jquerymobile with a link

Tags: php, css, hyperlink, stylesheet

I have a variable called `$cat`(which stands for 'category') in the URL.

Depending on whether it is "a" or "b" I swap the stylesheet using a link:

```
<?php
if($cat == "a") { ?> 
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styleA.css"> 
<?php }
elseif($cat == "b") { ?>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styleB.css"> 
<?php } ?>
```

styleA.css makes the `background-color` of the header blue, and styleB.css makes it red

`<div id="header" data-role="header" data-position='fixed'>...</div>`

if I click on a link that looks like this:

```
<a href="index.php?cat=a">Click for red</a>
<a href="index.php?cat=b">Click for blue</a>
```

the URL actually works (content is incuded depending on $cat) and I do get the value of $cat but the stylesheet does not seem to have swapped, since the color doesn't change. But if I reload the page (with the URL given by the link before) the stylesheets swap and everything works perfectly.

I used the same method for the desktop version of the website I'm working on and everything works perfectly fine.
This issue seems to only appear if I use jquery mobile.

Does anyone see why this isn't working as it should?

EDIT (adding html):
This is pretty much it, but here's the rest of it:

headpart:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://d10ajoocuyu32n.cloudfront.net/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css">
<!-- Extra Codiqa features -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/codiqa.ext.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
<?php if($cat == "a") { ?>  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styleASS.css"> <?php } 
      if($cat == "b")   { ?> <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styleBB.css"> <?php }
?>
<!-- jQuery and jQuery Mobile -->
<script src="https://d10ajoocuyu32n.cloudfront.net/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d10ajoocuyu32n.cloudfront.net/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Extra Codiqa features -->
<script src="https://d10ajoocuyu32n.cloudfront.net/codiqa.ext.js"></script>
</head>


<div data-role="page" id="page">
   <div id="panel_menu" data-role="panel" data-display="overlay">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li role="heading">Navigation</li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="header" data-role="header" data-position='fixed'>
        <h1>Header</h1>
        <a href="#panel_menu">Menu</a>
    </div>
     <div data-role="content">

     <?php include "$menu_page_content";?>

     <a href="?cat=a&lang=en&menu=home">a</a>
      <a href="?cat=b&lang=en&menu=home">b</a>

    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="d">
        <div data-role="navbar" class="ui-icon-nodisc">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#" id='language' data-icon='custom'>Change Language</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id='category' data-icon="custom" >Change Category</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id='contact' data-icon="custom" >Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- page -->
```

EDITIT:
Uploaded it to a free hoster: [here](http://knickie.site11.com)
You may either click on one of the links in the content area, or on "category" in the footer area. Click & reload the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If most of your styles are the same with the exception of the color I would suggest putting them in a single style sheet and writing in a class to the body.

For Example

```
 .header {
      /* general header styles margins paddings and whatnot */
 }

 .cat-a .header {
      background-color: red;
 }
 .cat-b .header {
      background-color: blue;
 }
```

Then variably write the class in on the body

```
 <body class='cat-<?php echo $cat; ?>'>
```

Answer (score 1):

It must depends on how data are cached on the browser you're using.

Several solutions are possible.

You could not swap CSS stylesheet, but add style properties using PhP or Javascript. That way you'll be 100% sure it will change. (As long as the user has javascript by the way, PhP would make it really 100% sure)

Or force the browser to reload CSS sheets everytime, but it's not a bandwidth friendly solution, I would not recommend that.

---

In case you want to use it to save user's choice and reload the correct background everytime, give a look at this :
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-44389.html

Didn't find any SO link though

Comment: I don't think that it depends on the device I'm using, since I have the issue on all devices I'm using (IE,FF,GC,iPhone/Pod/Pad,HTC One, ...). And of course you're right, I might just use JS, still I'd like to understand why this isn't working with PHP

Comment: Device isn't really what I meant sorry. It's much more about the browser. And most browser have the same behavior where they don't reload stylesheets all the time. I think mobile' browsers try to download it even less often that computers one, because the available bandwidth is not the same.

Comment: The issue occurs on every device in every browser that I am able to test it, in addition I use the exact same method on the desktop version of this website and it seems to work perfectly there. EDIT: desktop version also works on every mobile device (so far)

Comment: Ok, `This issue seems to only appear if I use jquery mobile.` this lost me. Could you add the HTML code to you question or upload it to any online tool so we can see it ?

Comment: The question now contains the complete HTML (page)

Comment: Sorry, I was much more looking for the headers part in fact. `<head>...</head>`

Comment: Would it be a problem to call another page `changeColor.php?color=blue` and use `header (Location: index.php)` for you or do you strictly want the user to stay on this page. Otherwise, the easiest solution would be to let the code that way, and add a `onClick` to change the color "virtually" until the next reload, where the problem will disappear.
Headers are currently just not being reloaded.

Comment: it wouldn't be a problem to solve this issue as you said with JS. Still I'd like to understand why it doesn't work.